# compile c++ project using vim

Tags: vim

I a new vim user, so i am trying to modify vim in order to fit to my needs.

Let's say that i have the project/main.cpp and project/build. Where inside the project/build when i do "make -j5 install" my project is being build and installed correctly. But when i am trying to do that inside from the vim it doesn't work. Here is the code which i use....

```
map <F5> :call BuildGitRepo()<cr>

function! BuildGitRepo() 
    :cd %:p:h
    let currentFileDir = :pw
    :cd currentFileDir
    :cd "build"
    :!make -j5 install
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim script from a vimrc file functions a bit differently from the Vim window. Commands that begin with `:` become native in vim script, meaning that you don't need the colon. Also, using local variables is a bit different - you need to use exec.

Finally, you can't capture the output of `:` commands without buffer redirection, but you can use the `getcwd()` function to get the current working directory. But it looks like you're `cd`ing to the current file's directory twice, so I've made that a bit simpler.

Here's a version of your function that should work in a vimrc file:

```
map <F5> :call BuildGitRepo()<cr>

function! BuildGitRepo() 
    exec "cd " . expand("%:p:h") ."/build"
    !make -j5 install
endfunction
```